# Incorrect dateime Value for column 'date' at row 1

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, wpf

I am trying to update my table named as 'permanent_days', in which i have a column, named 'date', as default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. I having error:

> > Incorrect dateime Value: '2016-09%' for column 'date' at row 1

This error is coming in following query:

```
query = "UPDATE permanent_days SET total_days='" + 
           sum + "' WHERE emp_id_fk='" + ForeignKey +
           "' AND date LIKE '" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM") + "%'";
                        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I am using phpmyadmin and WPF. Any help could be a great favor

Comment: Instead of `like` why not compare the year and month using [`DatePart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)?  Also you should consider using parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use like you should convert your date in string

```
 "UPDATE permanent_days SET total_days='"  + 
 sum + "' WHERE emp_id_fk='" + ForeignKey + 
 "' AND   DATE_FORMAT(`date` , '%Y-%m') LIKE '" + 
 DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM") + "%'";
```